# OpenSuse zypper is slow on startup

Tags: package-management, opensuse, zypper

Whenever I open the terminal to install something from the repositories, it takes like 1 minute to 'build' them and all that junk. I recently switched from Ubuntu and apt never had this issue. What can I do to reduce this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zypper auto-refreshes the repos when you run it. Disable it.

Head over to YaST, click on Software and then Software Repositories.

[image]

Next,Select the repo, and ensure that Automatically refresh is disabled.

[image]

Comment: thanks! is it safe to remove auto refresh on all repos?

Comment: @MaxMackie - yes, it is. I generally disable them since my 'net connection is slow. Just remember to do `zypper ref` before checking for updates to your packages.

Answer (score 1):

A modification on Sathyajith Bhat's answer is a command line to hit them all at once. Thanks @SathyajithBhat

```
sudo zypper modifyrepo -a -R
```

-R is legacy. -F should also work. If no name is specified, the action is done on all repos.

End result
[image]

Comment: nice complement! its working.